# Rank of $A$ and $A^{\theta}A$ are same

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

The original question was If $A$ is a real $m \times n$ matrix then show that rank of $A$ and $A^TA$ are same. The proof follows by showing that nullspace of both $A$ and $A^TA$ are same which is given as below:
$x\in N(A)\Rightarrow x\in N(A^TA)$
\begin{align}
x\in N(A^TA) &\Rightarrow A^TA(x)=0 \\ 
&\Rightarrow \langle x,A^TAx\rangle =0 \\
&\Rightarrow \langle Ax,Ax\rangle =0 \\
&\Rightarrow Ax=0 \\
&\Rightarrow x\in N(A).
\end{align}
Now with the same argument can we show that rank of $A$ and $A^{\theta}A$ are same where $A$ in a complex matrix? Here $\theta$ means conjugate transpose

Comment: $\theta$ being transposition + conjugation?

Comment: **[Hint]** : Consider the Schur-Jordan decomposition and note that $AA^{\theta}$ and $A^{\theta}A$ have the same positive eigenvalues

Comment: Yes, the same proof works for conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: show that in the complex case $\langle Au,v \rangle _m = \langle u,A^\theta v 
\rangle _n$ and repeat the argument from the real case using Rank Nullity.